# Sending APK file android

Tags: android, bluetooth, apk

I use this code to send the app's APK file to another device. It works on android 2.3.3, but is not working on android 4+.

Where is the problem?

I have logged the `getpackageCodePath()` and it returns the APK file on android 4+, but the whole code is not working, and when Bluetooth starts, it sends nothing.

```java
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
sendIntent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
uris.add(Uri.parse(getApplication().getPackageCodePath()));
sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null));
```

Comment: Are you sure your Android 4.0 device is equipped to handle bluetooth transfers? Have you tried to send a file over bluetooth using OI file manager or something?

Comment: yes ,  and I can send file via my phone with file managers

Comment: @Ata Did you got any answer?

Comment: nope , it seem that android 4 blocked operation on file accessign on original APK files

Comment: its not blocked, but it did change. see `getApplicationInfo().publicSourceDir`

Comment: [getApplicationInfo().publicSourceDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#publicSourceDir)

Comment: Are you sending APK within your App?

Answer (score 13):

I use below code for send apk. and it works

```
try{
    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    sendIntent.setType("application/*");
    uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(getApplicationInfo().publicSourceDir)));
    sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null));

}catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: +1 I tried this Code, it's working in Samsung devices but not working on Moto G2.
Please let me know how to sort out the issue

Answer (score 1):

Change the line :

```
uris.add(Uri.parse(getApplication().getPackageCodePath()));
```

to

```
uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(getApplicationInfo().publicSourceDir)));
```

and it should work in all 4.x devices. Alternatively you can also do something like this:

```
ApplicationInfo app=getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("packageName", 0);                       
uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(app.publicSourceDir)));
```

Both of the above ways work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getApplicationInfo().publicSourceDir` instead of `getApplication().getPackageCodePath()` to get the path to your app's APK, then use that in a `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` to send the file via Bluetooth.

Check here for an example:
[Bluetooth File transfer on Android(even restricted types)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277593/bluetooth-file-transfer-on-androideven-restricted-types/21790899#21790899)

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            File apkPublicFilePath = new File(
                    Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                    "myapk.apk");
            try {

                in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myapk);
                out = new FileOutputStream(apkPublicFilePath);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                // Close the streams
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error in copy files");
            }

            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,

            Uri.fromFile(apkPublicFilePath.getAbsoluteFile()));
            try {
                sendIntent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(
                        sendIntent,
                        PersianReshape.reshape(getResources().getString(
                                R.string.msg_send))));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                sendIntent.setType("*/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(
                        sendIntent,
                        PersianReshape.reshape(getResources().getString(
                                R.string.msg_send))));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it work:

```
// Get current ApplicationInfo to find .apk path
ApplicationInfo app = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();
String filePath = app.sourceDir;

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

// MIME of .apk is "application/vnd.android.package-archive".
// but Bluetooth does not accept this. Let's use "*/*" instead.
intent.setType("*/*");

// Only use Bluetooth to send .apk
intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");

// Append file and send Intent
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share app"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
sendIntent.setType("*/*");
uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(getApplicationInfo().publicSourceDir)));
sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null));
```

Use */* this worked for me